# duplicate xml dom objects in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, duplicates, cloning

I want to copy/clone 2 xml dom objects - one into another.

Sorry if it is duplicate question... I've already tried
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

But jquery throws Illegal invocation

**EDIT:** XML comes from an ajax call

```
function FetchXMLData() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "resources/data.xml",
                    data : requestVars,
                    dataType : 'xml',
                    success : function(xml) {
                        XMLParser(xml);
                        xmlOrig = $(xml).clone(); // I want to do something like this
                    },
                    error : function(xhr, err) {
                        ShowErrors(xhr, err);
                    }
                });
            }
```

**EDIT 2:** Now, I'm using javascript cloneNode, that works perfectly in IE and FF, but fails in Chrome. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45277). If anyone knows a workaround I would be grateful.

Comment: can you please show us some examples of what kind of xml you are talking about?

Comment: What does `XMLParser` do? Don't you have to assign what ever is returned from that method to a variable? `xml = XMLParser(xml)`

Comment: xmlParser just fetches some useful information from the xml file. I was trying to clone/replicate that xmlin order to keep the original structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but i just had this same problem, and solved it converting it to text and again to XML.

Having:

```
(...)
success : function(xml) {
    XMLParser(xml);
    xmlOrig = cloneXML(xml);
},
(...)

// auxiliar function to clone XML
function cloneXML(xml) {
    var xml_text = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);
    return $.parseXML(xml_text); // return XML document
}
```

This workaround worked for me in Firefox 49.0.2 and Chrome 54.0.2840.71.

If anyone know a better way, please answer.